# OpenGL camera jumps suddenly at first mouse input?

Tags: c++, opengl, mouselistener, glm-math

I have been using OpenGL to create a 3D first person shooter game. I decided to abstract the camera movement to a separate player class and I have managed to get these methods to work but my only problem is that the camera makes a big jump whenever the mouse first enters the screen.

I know that the fix for this is to check for the first time mouse is moved but I have done this however it still causes a jump. Here is the code:

```
void player::mouse_input(double &mouse_x_coordinate, double &mouse_y_coordinate, bool &first_mouse)
{
    if (first_mouse)
    {
        last_x = mouse_x_coordinate;
        last_y = mouse_y_coordinate;
        first_mouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = mouse_x_coordinate - last_x;
    float yoffset = last_y - mouse_y_coordinate;
    last_x = mouse_x_coordinate;
    last_y = mouse_y_coordinate;

    xoffset *= sensitivity;
    yoffset *= sensitivity;

    yaw += xoffset;
    pitch += yoffset;

    if (pitch > 89.0f)
        pitch = 89.0f;
    if (pitch < -89.0f)
        pitch = -89.0f;

    glm::vec3 front;
    front.x = cos(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    front.y = sin(glm::radians(pitch));
    front.z = sin(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    a_forward_direction = glm::normalize(front);
}
```

the `mouse_x_coordinate` and `mouse_y_coordinate` parameters are global variables containing the mouses x and y coordinates which I got through the `glfwSetCursorPosCallback()` function.

The `first_mouse` Boolean is also a global variable initialised as `true`.

Here is the initialisation of the a_forward_direction vector:

```
glm::vec3  a_forward_direction = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
```

after following through the mouse_input method, I find that the values for front should match but it still causes a jump.

Can anyone tell me why the mouse still jumps?

Comment: Are `pitch` and `yaw` properly initialized? And please fix your code formatting. (Btw. see `std::clamp`.)

Comment: If `yaw` and `pitch` are 0.0, the the initial value of `front` is (x=1, y=0, z=0). Is this intended?

Comment: yaw is -90 and pitch is 0 initially. Im not fully sure why yaw must be -90 to begin with because I got that you must do that from learnopengl however it worked as -90 when the mouse input was a function in the main file

Comment: *"yaw is -90 and pitch is 0 initially"* - So initially `front` is (x=0, y=0, z=-1)

Comment: What @Rabbid76 is saying: Make sure that your initial value for `a_forward_direction` matches whatever you calculate from the initial angles. The best way to do this is to extract the calculation of the direction into a separate method and call that in the constructor as soon as the initial angles are set up.

Comment: Oh ok I think I understand what you mean so I will edit the question to include the initialization of the a_forward_direction vector. After looking at the value of this vector and following through to the initial value of front, I find that they match as (x=0, y=0, z=0)